# How to play video file from asset library using AVPlayerLayer

Tags: iphone, video, alasset, avplayerlayer

Im trying to play alasset MOV file from asset library. Does anyone use AVPlayerLayer? 
if yes some hist will be great...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *myMovieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:_vUrl.absoluteString];
AVURLAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:myMovieURL options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:playerItem];
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
[_playerlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"readyForDisplay" options:0 context:nil];

((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds = ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer]).bounds;
[(AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer] setPlayer:_player];
_playerlayer = (AVPlayerLayer *)[self layer];
[_player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't get the actual file-path from the AssetsLibrary because of sandboxing. However, you have various options to access/play the video file.

1) Query the URL of the Asset using the url method of ALAssetRepresentation and pass it to an instance of MPMoviePlayerController to play the video. This url starts with assets-library:// and is not a file-system url, but MPMoviePlayerController knows how to handle such an URL.

2) Get the video contents by using the getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: of ALAssetsRepresentation to save the video to your own app sandbox to play/edit/share it or use getBytes:fromOffset:length:error: to stream the video contents.

Comment: i already have the url in that form but (assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=6309B178-2070-42CE-8BA8-31A4BEA16F5E&ext=MOV) but the player not start, all i see is black screen . btw im debugging on my iphone  so there no sandboxing issue.